# SublimeLinter 3 - How to ignore specific "not defined" warnings

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I want to know if there is any way to ignore/exclude the "is not defined" warning on Sublime Linter 3, because I'm using it with Jasmine, and it does not identify the `browser` word, then it keeps saying it is not defined.

Is there any configuration parameter, like `'ignore': ['browser', 'by', 'element']`

P.S: I just need it to be disable in the matched cases above.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sublime Linter was using jshint, the solution was add this line to the file:

```
/* globals element */
/* globals by */
/* globals browser */
```

And the warnings will never appear for this cases.